# NET 5 WebAPI + OData - custom result model

Tags: odata, .net-5

Am I able to make this prittier with custom model/class?

```json
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#Customers",
    "@odata.count": 4830,
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Code": "",
            "Name1": "",
            "Name2": "",
            "Name3": ""
        },
             ...
```

I don't need `@data.context` and I want to be able to add response message for zero results.

For example:

```json
    "responseMessage": "Example message from API with OData",
    "responseCode": 10,
    "itemsLength": 4830,
    "items": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Code": "",
            "Name1": "",
            "Name2": "",
            "Name3": ""
        },
             ...
```

Also I want to handle exeptions with same model

For example:

```json
    "responseMessage": "[Exception.Message] - Exception message example text.",
    "responseCode": -1,
    "itemsLength": 0,
    "items": []
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

OData works best with EF as it "forces" to use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. In my case, I can't use EF because it's not my database, so I'm using Dapper. We all know that Dapper lives by different laws and `IQueryable` does not provide any benefits but thanks to this it is possible to return a custom response using OData:

**MODEL**

```cs
    public class CustomersResponse
    {
        public string ReponseMessage { get; set; }
        public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
        public int ItemsLength { get; set; }
        public IQueryable Items { get; set; }
    }
```

**KONTROLER**

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Customer> options)
        {
            var response = new CustomersResponse();

            try
            {
                var customers = await _dataReader.GetCustomers("database_name");
                var customersResult = options.ApplyTo(customers.AsQueryable()).Cast<Customer>();
                if(customersResult.Count() == 0)
                {
                    response.ItemsLength = customers.Count();
                    response.ReponseMessage = "NotFound";
                    response.ResponseCode = 404;
                    response.Items = customersResult;
                    return NotFound(response);
                }
                response.ItemsLength = customers.Count();
                response.ReponseMessage = "OK";
                response.ResponseCode = 200;
                response.Items = customersResult;
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.ResponseCode = 500;
                response.Items = null;
                response.ReponseMessage = ex.Message;
                response.ItemsLength = 0;
                return StatusCode(500, response);
            }
        }
```

We remove the `[EnableQuery]` attribute from the endpoint, add the `ODataQueryOptions<Customer> options` parameter and use `options.ApplyTo()`, which will prepare the data accordingly. I would like to remind you that this is on average efficient, because we collect all customers in the first line, and then we filter using OData.

**WORKS**

```cs
.Filter()
.OrderBy()
.SetMaxTop(50)
```

**DOESN'T WORK**

```cs
.Count() // we don't need that anymore
.Expand()
.Select()
```

In the case of `Select()` there is most likely a problem with the returned data as OData tries to convert it to its type somehow.

```
{
    "reponseMessage": "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectSome`1[OptimoLogic.Models.Customer]' to type 'OptimoLogic.Models.Customer'.",
    "responseCode": 500,
    "itemsLength": 0,
    "items": null
}
```